# What are the best conditions for Peperomia caperata?

Tags: houseplants, indoors

This is the plant, [Peperomia caperata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peperomia_caperata) that I like for my bedroom and living room.

Rooms have windows but receive only some daylight and no sunlight. We have to use tubelight for these rooms, all the time.

The country is India, and region is Delhi. There is 2.6 years old active toddler in the house. At night in summers we may use air conditioners.

- **What is the life expectancy of this plant?**
- **Will it be better if I get the seeds and start from scratch or should I buy a grown up plant?**
- **What do I need to know and do to ensure the long life of that plant?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would not recommend peperomia as a houseplant for someone new to plants.  It is a nice looking plant from Brazil but requires a fairly exact watering regime and does not tolerate less than ideal light conditions.  That is why this plant can be short lived for some people.

You are always better off to start from an established plant and [they propagate easily](http://plantsarethestrangestpeople.blogspot.ca/2009/01/golden-girls-peperomia-caperata-and-p.html) from leaf or stem cuttings placed in water or moist rooting substrate like vermiculite.

They tolerate high temperatures [but not low temperatures below 15 degrees](http://www.greenobsessions.com/meet-the-peppers/) Celsius.

They are challenging to cultivate because their roots are very fine and not deep. They are best in higher than average humidity with bright diffuse light or they can wilt and overwatering is a constant problem.  Potting in too large a pot or in heavy peat based soils can encourage root rot.  To sum up this plant wants to be moist at all times without being wet.

There are numerous cultivars with speckled leaves or different shades.  They are not heavy feeders so fertilizing once or twice a year with a dilute houseplant fertilizer (20-20-20) should do.

The flowers are creamy white flower spikes.  In a good location there will be multiple spikes at once.

A [terrarium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrarium) is ideal for these plants if potted with a free draining soil in diffuse light so this might work for you and keep the plant out the hands of young children.